# Font frame in css file

Tags: html, css, font-face, icon-fonts

I want to use a font frame in my webpage. The font frame is like the [Brownstone](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/brownstone-slab/sans-frames-hole/) font frame so if you type the letter e for example it is a large curly frame.I would like to put these frames around images on a webpage.

The obvious way I can think to do it would be to type the letter e in a span with a class with the font-family of Brownstone frame using @fontface and style it from there but is there a way of doing this with purely css and not having to type e in a span which would seem like bad markup?

I havn't found any similar questions and havn't figured out a better way than what I've suggested.

Comment: Could you use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to generate your required letter?

Comment: Like so?

div:before {
    content: "e";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'font-frame-family';
    }

I'll give that a go.